# ReactNative TextInput' onChangeText is not called

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I want `onTextChange` to be triggered when I set text to it through state changes. I am building my on screen number keyboard to enter a pin code, and I want to catch text changes on `TextInput` when user presses these keys.

```
this.setState({text})
```

My `TextInput` looks like this:

```
<TextInput
  editable={false}
  onChangeText={text => Alert.alert(text)}
  secureTextEntry={true}
  value={this.state.text}
```

**UPD:** I found somehow related question, but it too doesn't have an answer: [TextInput not working as expected when programmatically entering text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42976735/5222156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `onContentSizeChange`, which gets called when text changes. I did find that some TextInput methods doesn't work properly when text is set programmatically.

Comment: Awesome mate. Thank you so much!

Comment: How did you use onContentSizeChange exactly? you can't get the value of text in onContentSizeChange as far as I know.

Comment: @Lucky_girl As far as I remember I used it to only track changes in TextInput; not to get the value of TextInput

Answer (score 2):

You set the `editable` prop to `false` then `TextInput`'s text will never change and `onChangeText` will never call...

Comment: The text changes, I checked that. Although when I set editable to true, and change text through system keyboard onChangeText calls works as intended.

Comment: so check it too: onChangeText={(text) => {alert(text)}}

Answer (score 1):

I think the event handler function for onChangeText is asynchronous, hence you should use async/await

```
<Input onChangeText={(val) => { this.changeHandler(val) }} />
```

and the change handler method should be

```
changeHandler = async (val) =>{
  await this.setState({
    [someKey]: val
 })
  .
  .
  .
  do other stuff that depends on val
}
```

it worked for previously to make http request which is fired when input value changes, and uses the input value.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't bind for it:

```
onChangeText={text => Alert.alert(text)}
```

should change:

```
onChangeText={this.changeFunction.bind(this)}
```

then add a function:

```
changeFunction(text){
   alert(text);
}
```

=> You can test then vote me down if it not work :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You may use it like below.

```
class MyComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { text: null }   //By default it will be null.
    this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this)  //You need to bind your function here.
  }

  _handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;  //it will destructure your name and value where ever you are using _handleChange method.
        this.setState({
            [name]: value // here we are setting the state dynamically.
        });
        alert(value)
    }

   render() {
     return(
       <View>
         <TextInput
           editable={true}
           onChangeText={this._handleChange}  // this will call _handleChange method.
           secureTextEntry={true}
           value={this.state.text}/>       
       </View>
     )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code maybe help you:

```
     this.state = {Alert.alert(
                         'Update available //your Title',
                         'Keep your app up to date to enjoy the latest 
                          features //your Message',
                          [
                            {
                             text: 'Cancel',
                             onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                             style: 'cancel',
                             }
                           ]
                      )
    }
    <TextInput
      editable={false}
      onChangeText={text => Alert.alert(text)}
      secureTextEntry={true}
      value={this.state.text}
    />
```